# How to pop back viewController from SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

In my app after pressing the login button in my loginViewController, it push to front viewController of my `SWRevealViewController`. In my `RearViewController` I have the sign out button. When I press it it should pop to the back viewController again (LoginViewController). But even though I set the button click event like this it doesnt navigate to the loginViewController.

```
-(void)signOutClick :(id)sender
    {
      [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(moveToLoginView) withObject:nil];
    }

-(void)moveToLoginView
    {
      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

But when I swipe the view it gose to the back view.I want to disable that swipe feature to the back view. And I want to go to the back view when click on the sign out button in my `RearViewController`. How can I do that? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but instead of using

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

try using,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And to stop swipe gesture you can use code like,

```
-  (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the stack of navigation controller. If you get the controller you want, just pass that controller for pop.

Answer (score -2):

You need to reset the top view controller if you want to perform these kind of actions off of a click. E.g.

*get an instance of the ECSlidingViewController*

```
ECSlidingViewController *slidingController = self.slidingViewController;
```

*get the view controller you wish to be on the top*

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

*set the topViewController property*

```
slidingController.topViewController = nc;
[slidingController resetTopViewAnimated:NO];
```